# Cache content of QWebView for offline usage

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwebview

I wish to use a QWebView in application, which most of time is in offline state. Even then it should present as up to date data as it is possible.

For example - user visits the stackoverflow.com webpage via QWebView. After 2-3 days he wish to visit the same webpage, however he is in offline state. As a result he gets the last available content.

**The question** - Is it possible to easily add an offline storage to QWebView instance?

Comment: Only thing that I can think of is possibly have another thread / process scrape the content of the website and save it for offline use?

Comment: This might help -> http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsettings.html#setOfflineWebApplicationCachePath